# Fundamental theorem of calculus with a piece wise function

Tags: calculus

The problem is:
Let

$$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 
       0 & & x < 0 \Large\strut \\
       x & & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \Large\strut \\
       2-x & & 1 \leq x \leq  2 \Large\strut \\
       0 & & x>2 \Large\strut \end{array} \right.$$

and let  $$g(x) =\int^x_0 f(t)\ dt $$
Find a formula for $g(x)$ that doesn't involve integrals.

How would I procede to integrate $f(x)$ with each value? The problem that confuses me is that there are two variables. There is a $g(x)$ variable, $x$, that effects the upper bound of the integral. Then there is the $x$ in $f(x)$, which would be $t$, but how would I integrate the piece wise the function in this condition with $g(x) $.

Comment: Draw a picture. Your function is a triangle. In fact, if $y\geqslant 2$, $g(y)=g(2)$, and if $y\leqslant 0$, $g(y)=g(0)=0$, so $g$ is constant over those rays. Worry about the triangle.

Comment: $f$ has jumps at $x \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ so we expect the derivative of $g$ to have jumps in the same places.  It's like we expect $g$ to be another piecewise function depending on $x$...

Comment: How would I integrate that with the two different functions?

Comment: Hint: take Pedro's advice and draw a picture of $f$; think about what the function $g(x)$ measures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\leq 0$, $g(x)=\int_0^x 0dt =0$.

For $0\leq x \leq 1$ , $g(x)=\int_0^x tdt=x^2/2$.

For $1\leq x\leq2$, $g(x)=\int_0^1 tdt +\int_1^x (2-t)dt=2x -x^2/2 -1$.

For $x\geq 2$, $g(x)=\int_0^1 tdt +\int_1^2 (2-t)dt + \int_2^x 0dt=1$.

The idea is to break the integral up as a sum of integrals on intervals where each piece of the piecewise-defined integrand lives, using the fact that $\int_a^c=\int_a^b +\int_b^c$.

And since the upper limit is variable, how you break it up will depend on what the upper limit is; I've considered all the possibilities above. Putting them all together,

$$
g(x)=
 \begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      x^2/2 & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      2x-x^2/2 - 1& 1\leq x\leq 2 \\
      1 & x \geq 2
   \end{cases}
$$

Comment: Why does the integral vary between 1 and x?

Comment: Because you have to break the interval $[0,x]$ into the two pieces where $f$ has different definitions. For example, if you want to find $g(1.7)$, you are integrating $f$ over $[0,1.7]$. But $f$ has pieces defined differently in $[0,1]$ and $[1,2]$. So integrate each piece separately, using $f(t)=t$ on $[0,1]$ and $f(t)=2-t$ on $[1,2]$. You only need part of the 2nd interval since you are only integrating up to $x=1.7$ there; that is, $f(t)=2-t$ on $[1,1.7]$ because $[1,1.7]\subset[1,2]$.

Comment: In other words, to compute $g(1.7)$ you need to integrate from $0$ to $1.7$. But the definition of $f$ forces you to do this piecewise, first from $0$ to $1$ and then from $1$ to $1.7$. Make sense?

Comment: Ah ok, and that's how you can get an equation for g(x) that doesn't use integrals?

Comment: Yes, I've made it more explicit by putting it all together to write $g$ as a piecewise-defined function. See answer, at end, above.